# Inputting strings until a word is entered

Tags: java

I'm a bit of newbie with Java, so bear with me.
I'm trying to write a program which takes in user input, until a certain word is entered, at which point the program terminates.
I so far have this:

```
public class Question {

    private String getInput() {
        Input in = new Input();
        System.out.print("Enter String: ");
        String line = reader.readLine();
    }

    public void method() {

        while (!"end".equals(line)) {
            System.out.println(line);
            line = reader.readLine(); // read next line
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Question().getInput();
    }
}
```

can anyone explain what might be going wrong?

Comment: Not until you tell us what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This code will not even compile.

```
private String getInput()
{
    Input in = new Input();
    System.out.print("Enter String: ");
    String line = reader.readLine(); // reader does not exist
}
```

Please at least make an effort to identify and fix problems before posting.  Surely the compiler warned you (or would have warned you) that it doesn't know what `reader` is.  Presumably, you copied this code from a website, but didn't copy all of it.  The `reader` variable must first be defined, and seeing as you are trying to access its `readLine()` method, it is likely meant to be of type `BufferedReader`.

To make it more clear, try this line of code:

`BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));`

This will instantiate reader as you want it.  And you can remove this:

`Input in = new Input();`

because you are not using it.

Comment: But I explained it in my answer.  If something is not clear you can ask a follow-up question.

Comment: The other error here is that getInput() is defined to return a String but there is no return statement.   You need to add "return line;" as the last line in the method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a variable named `reader` that is available at that line, and that is of a type that has a `readLine()` method that returns string. What you most likely want to do is something like

```
BufferReader reader = new BufferReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

Take a look [here](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/io/ReadStandardIO.shtml) for more details.

Comment: @danben, oops! Guess I didn't read the link carefully enough either :P